# Openshift new-app from local Docker image

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm trying to deploy on an Openshift Origin Pod an image which is available in my Docker repository:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tomcat9demo                                  latest              535da1774da0        9 weeks ago         350.2 MB
```

When running:

```
$ oc new-app tomcat9demo --name tomcatdemo
```

Apparently it seems to find the image from the Docker repository:

```
--> Found Docker image 535da17 (9 weeks old) from  for "tomcat9demo:latest"

    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "tomcat9demo"
    * Port 8080/tcp will be load balanced by service "tomcat9demo"
      * Other containers can access this service through the hostname "tomcat9demo"
    * WARNING: Image "tomcat9demo:latest" runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator

--> Creating resources with label app=tomcat9demo ...
    deploymentconfig "tomcat9demo" created
    service "tomcat9demo" created
--> Success
```

However the status shows an error. It seems there's an error with the image pull:

```
$ oc get pods
NAME                           READY     STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
tomcat9demo-1-zrj98            0/1       ErrImagePull   0          16s
$ oc status
Error from server: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Do I need something else to grab the image from my local Docker repository ?

Comment: How are you running OpenShift? Using ``oc cluster up``, ``minishift``, or a remote OpenShift environment?

Comment: Thanks I'm running Openshift origin with "oc cluster up --version=latest"

Comment: Personally never found a backdoor for doing ``docker build`` and it being usable immediately. Technically believe you still need to expose the internal OpenShift registry and do a ``docker push`` into it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton any handy pointers on how to do that?  Carla did you  get this working?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624945/unable-to-push-a-docker-image-to-local-openshift-origin-registry

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the option --docker-image for it to point to your local image repo. Example:

oc new-app tomcat9demo --docker-image tomcat9demo

Answer (score 0):

You should add a tag to the local docker image.

```
docker build -t image_name .
docker tag image_name:<current tag ot just a latest> image_name:<new tag>
oc new-app mage_name:<new tag> --name=app_name
```

And you should see:

```
Found Docker image <your docker image id> (19 minutes old) from  for "image_name:<new tag>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this awesome youtube video, I was able to successfully deploy my local docker image onto the dedicated openshift platform's docker registry with the help of this:
[Push local docker images to openshift registry - minishift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5VzXvvkiL4)

Hope it helps.